# Effiecient way to trim an array

Tags: arrays, swift

Let's say I have a struct…

```
struct Person {
   let isMale: Bool
   let name: String
}
```

and an array of `Person` structs. I want to trim all the men (`isMale == true`) from the *start* and *end* of the array (similarly to how you'd trim whitespace from the start & end of a string)…

```
func trimMen(people: [Person]) -> [Person]

    var trimmedPeople: [Person] = people

    while trimmedPeople.first?.isMale {
        trimmedPeople.removeFirst()
    }
    while trimmedPeople.last?.isMale {
        trimmedPeople.removeLast()
    }
    return trimmedPeople
}
```

Is there a more efficient way in Swift way to do it?

Comment: This seems perfectly fine and very readable. Don't try to be clever with the sole purpose of reducing lines of code.

Comment: "a more Swift-y way" seems like purely a matter of opinion, to the extent that it has any meaning at all

Comment: I removed my answer because I think I missed read originally. You want to keep males in the middle of the array, just remove from the ends?

Comment: Another possible solution is to first find the index of the first female and then  remove the prefix to that index.

Comment: 2 down-votes? If there's something wrong with the question please let me know so I can clarify

Comment: The question is fine but it's off topic.

Comment: @Sulthan Ah, my bad. Is there a better SE place to ask this?

Comment: I don't see how it is off-topic?

Comment: In terms of complexity every time you call the function `removeFirst()` inside you first while loop it takes `O(self.count)` so in the worst case is `(O(self.count)^2)`, you are dealing with arrays remember that, in the other case there is no problem because `removeLast()` takes `O(1)`. It's better to save the first index and the last index and extract the subarray from `[firstIndex...lastIndex]`. It's a suggestion to improve your code. And remember it's not always about the shortest way instead you should use the optimal way

Comment: It belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, probably.

Comment: @onnoweb It's unclear. How do you define "swifty"? More functional? Without `var`? Is it opinion based? Probably yes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I believe it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah @RogerLipscombe indeed it belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Done ( I guess if I'd used the word efficient in the title rather then Swiftest I'd have been OK!)

Comment: @AshleyMills No, unless it was being done in an extremely stupid way then yes, but this as Spoek has already mentioned is very much readable and therefore it belongs to codeReview

Comment: @AshleyMills: as the question was closed while I was writing an answer, here my idea: https://gitlab.com/snippets/24698 first get all males from the array, than take first and last males, filter the original array for not Persons not being first or last male.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest way I can think of is:

```
//Find the first occurrence of a non-male person
let firstIndex = people.index(where: {!$0.isMale}) ?? 0

//Find the last occurrence of a non-male person and calculate the end index accordingly
let lastIndex = people.count - 1 - 
                (people.reversed().index(where: {!$0.isMale}) ?? 0)

//Create an array of the subsequence.
let trimmedPeople = Array<Person>(people[firstIndex...lastIndex])
```

Comment: I would also extract that `isMale` condition into a closure parameter.

Comment: That would crash with an empty array. That wouldn't work with a single male element.

Comment: Also if I have an array with two males it would return the same array